# Error while uploading privacy url to developer.facebook.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, privacy-policy

In facebook for developers, when I am checking a URL in haring debugger, I am getting a response code of 206 with the following error:

Inferred Property: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Is it some tag I am missing that is causing a response code of 206 to be returned along with warnings rather than response code of 200.

[image]

Comment: why do you need an og:image for a privacy url? that is not an error, it is a warning.

Comment: @luschn - thank you for your response. We are getting a response code - 206 due to which we thought that this warning needs to be removed to get the status code 200.